# Is memcache impacting my performence negatively?

Tags: database, centos5, memcached, drupal, memcache

I am using pressflow 6 and NewRelic seems to suggest that memcache is infact hurting performance as shown below :

[image: DB Vs Memcache Load]

**My settings.php file :**

```
# Varnish reverse proxy on localhost
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;           
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1'); 

# Memcached configuration
$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
         '127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default',
         );
### END Mercury settings written on 2011-11-01T07:12:49-04:00
```

Comment: What part of that makes you think that memcache is negatively impacting performance?

Comment: Disable memcache and see what happens. I have a feeling you won't like the result...

Comment: Page rendering is taking more time in memcache then in DB... am I missing something in reading the chart above ?

Comment: If those numbers are right, your performance problems are not coming from Drupal, your database, or memcached. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Can you post the output of `top` when the site is slow, or maybe a minute or two of `dstat`?

Comment: If not drupal, db or memcache then what ? Newrelic is showing these taking time ?

Comment: @tom-oconnor Here's the top output : [link](http://notepad.cc/share/mb37EDe4yZ)